# Stripe charge and subscribe customer to muliple plans at once

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm new to Stripe and really like how simple the implementation is. But despite that, I'm still having some difficulties finding the best way to implement it into my e-commerce site.

In this site, a customer can add to cart a regular item and subscription item. For example like this:

```
Item A                   $ 10
Item B                   $ 20
Subscription C (Monthly) $ 10
Subscription D (Weekly)  $ 5
```

And at checkout, I want to process all those items at once.

I am thinking of implementing it like this:

First create the customer

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example customer")
);
```

Then charge the regular item price (30$ from example above)

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 3000, 
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

Then charge the subscriptions using for loop

```
foreach ($plans as $plan_id) {
  \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    "plan" => $plan_id
  ));
}
```

But I'm feeling that my code above is not the correct way to do this. Also it would result in many charges (as many as the subscription) and I don't think its a good idea.

I would like some advice on how to properly solve this problem.

I highly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!